# WPF Changing Page Color or Control Properties from a Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a `Method` in a `Class` that I can call if a value is true or false, this is simply a way to alert a user that something is wrong. I do not want to write the same code throughout the program. I need to change both the background color of the Window which holds the Frame and the logo on the page which is active in the Frame.

I have something like this but it is not working:

```
    public static BitmapImage ErrorStatus()
    {
        var imgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri
        (@"../MyFolder/ErrorImg.png", UriKind.Relative));
        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
        Brush errorColor = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#B90000");
        errorColor.Freeze();
        return imgSource;          
    }
```

Below is kind of working but only changes the color of the MainWindow. I need to change both the page image and the Window color using one Method, ***if possible***.

This changes the color of the `MainWindow`:

```
    public static void ErrorStatus()
    {
        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
        Brush errorColor = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#B90000");
        errorColor.Freeze();
        mainWindow.Background = errorColor;
    }
```

Finally I am calling the `Method` like this in a `KeyUp Event` on the `Page`.

```
        if (UserEntry == bad)
        {
         MyClass.ErrorStatus() //Call Method from class to change color.

         MyIndicator.Source = new BitmapImage(
         new Uri(@"/MyFolder/ErrorImg.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
         MyClass.SuccessStatus() //Call another Method to reset color.
         MyIndicator.Source = new BitmapImage(
         new Uri(@"/MyFolder/SuccessImg.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Comment: it is indeed possible, however the approach you are using defeats the features provided by WPF. could you share the sample of your xaml, which contains the relevant elements? do you use View model ie. DataContext in this application?

Comment: No, I simply have one Window containing a Frame and about 4 pages. Very basic app.